# ¿Cómo obtener el tiempo que dura una actividad?

Tags: java, android

Me gustaría obtener el tiempo que pasa desde que se inicia una actividad hasta que se ejecuta un click en uno de sus botones.

Me imagino que tengo de declarar algo en **onCreate()**

Y luego obtener el valor que ha pasado desde que se ejecutó el onCreate() hasta que se pulsa el botón llamado por ejemplo `bt1`:

```
 bt1.setOnClickListener(new AdapterView.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick( View view) {
            //Aquí se guardaría el tiempo...
            siguienteActividad();
```

¿Pero cómo?

Comment: He corregido mi respuesta, había agregado por error la variable tiempoInicial en todas partes :-( @AntonioRuiz

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Podrias obtener los milisegundos en cada lugar, y comparar

antes del **onCreate()** declaras dos variables de tipo Date

```
Date inicio, actual;
```

luego, dentro de 
**onCreate()** obtienes la hora y fecha actual de la siguiente manera

```
inicio= Calendar.getInstance().getTime();
```

y en tu evento click vuelves a obtener la hora y fecha actual, y restas los milisegundos de que cada **Date** nos devuelve, obtendriamos cuandos milisegundos pasaron, dividimos entre 1000 y tenemos segundo, dividimos entre 60 y tenemos minutos, y asi puedes seguir dividiendo

```
bt1.setOnClickListener(new AdapterView.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick( View view) {

        actual = Calendar.getInstance().getTime();

        //tiempo en minutos
        double tiempo=(actual.getTime()-inicio.getTime())/1000/60;

        siguienteActividad();
```

Answer (score 0):

Puedes usar tiempo en milisegundos o fechas para cualquier tarea.

Necesitas tres pasos:

1. Captura el tiempo inicial.
2. Llama la tarea o método que quieres analizar.
3. Muestra el tiempo transcurrido desde el inicio.

Aquí unos ejemplos:

Con tiempo en milisegundos transcurridos:

```
Long inicio = System.currentTimeMillis();
actividad();
System.out.println(System.currentTimeMillis()-inicio);
// Puedes obtener los segundos dividiendo entre mil
System.out.println((System.currentTimeMillis()-inicio)/1000);
```

Con tiempo transcurrido usando un objecto fecha:

```
Long inicio = System.currentTimeMillis();
Date fechaInicio = new Date(inicio);
System.out.println("Inicio: "+ fechaInicio);
actividad();
System.out.println(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis()-inicio));
```

Answer (score -2):

La idea que tienes es correcta, como comentas puedes obtener el valor en milisegundos de la hora inicial al iniciarse la Activity, esto dentro de `onCreate()` y al dar clic al botón obtener la hora final.

Para obtener el tiempo transcurrido en segundos, se puede realizar:

```
(tiempoFinal - tiempoInicial)/1000
```

Pero **es importante también, asignar el correcto listener al botón, en este caso debe ser `OnClickListener` de la vista**:

```
bt1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

             //Aquí agregar lo que deseas realizar.

            }
        });
```

---

Este es un ejemplo completo en el cual agrego comentarios como explicación:

```
private long tiempoInicial;
private long tiempoFinal;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        tiempoInicial = System.currentTimeMillis();


        //Define listener a botón.
        Button bt1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
        bt1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                 //Define tiempo inicio.
                 tiempoFinal = System.currentTimeMillis();

                //Obtiene tiempo transcurrido.
                System.out.println("Tiempo Tanscurrido " + (tiempoFinal - tiempoInicial) + " milisegundos.");
                System.out.println("Tiempo Tanscurrido " + (tiempoFinal - tiempoInicial)/1000 + " segundos.");

               //Reinicia tiempo inicio.
               tiempoInicial = System.currentTimeMillis();


            }
        });
 }
```

---

Si deseas reiniciar el tiempo después de dar click y obtener el tiempo transcurrido, simplemente obtén el `tiempoInicial` al realizar el calculo.

```
         ...
         ...

            //Obtiene tiempo transcurrido.
            System.out.println("Tiempo Tanscurrido " + (tiempoFinal - tiempoInicial) + " milisegundos.");
            System.out.println("Tiempo Tanscurrido " + (tiempoFinal - tiempoInicial)/1000 + " segundos.");

           //Reinicia tiempo inicio.
           tiempoInicial = System.currentTimeMillis();
        ...
            ...
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]